# I'm trying to fetch my json site to enable API, but but got an error "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Error while I'm trying to fetch my Json site. The error is "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

I fixed an error before related with disable CORS through {'mode': 'no-cors'}. And after that hppended this problem above

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const url =("http://localhost/v1/Items/GetHardWaretypes", {'mode': 'no-cors'} );

    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)
    this.setState({products: data.results, loading: false})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the headers `Content-Type` and `Accept` as `application/json`.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const url =("http://localhost/v1/Items/GetHardWaretypes", {'mode': 'no-cors'} );

  const response = await fetch(url, { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  this.setState({products: data.results, loading: false})
}
```

Comment: @Mosalah Have you tried to call this endpoint in Postman (or any other client)? Which response you get?

Comment: **Yes my friend, I tried it in Postman and it's working normally. The result is this:** {"watermark":"2019-09-28T00:21:19.8283624+02:00","items":["Övrigt","Virtuell dator","Terminal","Telefoni","Surfplatta","Stationär dator","Skrivare svart","Skrivare färg","Skanner","Projektor","Nätverk övrigt","Nätverk trådlöst","Nätverk switch","Nyckelskåp","Multimaskin","Mobiltelefon","Konferensutrustning","Interaktiv skrivtavla","Dockningsenhet","Datortillbehör","Computer","Bärbar dator","Bildskärm","A/V"]}  **I'm sick because of this error.. please help**

Comment: @Mosalah can you replace `await response.json();` with `await response.text();`, **temporarily**, just to test and see what's being printed in `console.log`? Just to see what the server is returning. It's returning something that's not a valid JSON. You could alternatively check the endpoint result on the Network tab on the browser.

Comment: @ Alberto, it's working excellent with all other json fake data, Just mine doesn't working, although it's returning json in the browser when I load it as a link. I did as you said to replace text instead of json and it's returning in consloe as HTML file , but with json fake data returning the same json data like in the browser. What you think man, what am i suppose to do now?

Comment: @Mosalah What's the content of this HTML file?

Comment: **@Alberto this is one part of whole content:**  <!-- manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/-->
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
<!--Notice the use of  in the tags above.
It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.

Comment: **And this the second part**  Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.-->
<title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div><!--This HTML file is a template. If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.  You can add webfonts,meta tags, or analytics to this file.The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.  To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`. -->

Comment: **This is the last part** <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script><script src="/main.c237327e0a5fa155d4ce.hot-update.js"></script></body>
</html>

Comment: @Mosalah That's so odd. I don't see how the endpoint returns the desired JSON when being called from Postman, and returns, at the same time, this HTML when being called from the browser :/. I'm sorry I can't help. Let's see if someone else, upon reading all these comments, figures out what might be wrong. Editing your question, adding as much details as possible, might also help.